# Select / deselect, change color of multiple panels created dynamically

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I use a list of objects as an input for my application and the number of objects in the list changes. For each object in the list I dynamically create a Panel and add them to the controls of other panel

```
    private void addPanel(string name, int positionFromLeft, Panel mainPanel)
    {
        Panel panel = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
        panel.Name = name;
        panel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(50 + positionFromLeft, 160);
        panel.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.SteelBlue;
        panel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(120, 40);
        panel.Click += new EventHandler(this.pClick);            
        mainPanel.Controls.Add(panel);
    }
```

To each panel I add a click event handler which changes the color of the panel:

```
    private void pClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Panel panel= (sender as Panel);
        panel.BackColor = Color.Green;
    }
```

How can I change a color to a different one (red etc.) of each panel when it's clicked second time? And change it back (to green etc.) when clicked again. Basically, with every click to change color of a panel from green to red and vice versa. It has to work with every panel, so that I can change color of, for example, 10 panels to green and 10 panels to red, and vice versa during the run time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got it right, you want to toggle the clicked panel.

```
private void pClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Panel panel = (sender as Panel);
    if (panel.BackColor == Color.Green) {
        panel.BackColor = Color.Red;
    } else if (panel.BackColor == Color.Red) {
        panel.BackColor = Color.Green;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not all of them, only the ones clicked. Changing color back and forward. Basically I need to capture the current clicking state for every panel created dynamically.

Comment: Then the new solution is the proper one. You can toggle between the current `BackColor` and the new `BackColor` you want to set.

Comment: This solution is not going to work, because initial color is not green, but SteelBlue.

Comment: From SteelBlue on the first click it has to change to green and on second click to red and third green and so on.